# Node js Google Routes Library Field Mask

Tags: node.js, google-routes-api

I'm trying to use Node Js Google Library the method compute Routes.
But in every execution i try i have:
"catch getPathFromGoogle Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: FieldMask is a required parameter. See https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters on how to provide it. As an example, you can set the header 'X-Goog-FieldMask' to value 'routes.distanceMeters,routes.duration,routes.polyline.encodedPolyline' to ask for the route distance, duration, and polyline in the response. You can also set the value to '*' in manual testing to get all the available response fields. However, using the '*' wildcard is discouraged in production.'"
How can i send this info to this method?

Here is my code:

```
                r = await routingClient.computeRoutes({
                    params: {
                        origin: { lat: origin[1], lng: origin[0] },
                        destination: {lat: dest[1], lng: dest[0]}
                      },
                      timeout: 1000
                });
```

An example of a code working with this method and how put X-Goog-FieldMask would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example:

```
import routing from "@googlemaps/routing";
import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library";

const routingClient = new routing.v2.RoutesClient({
  authClient: new GoogleAuth().fromAPIKey(
    "YOUR_API_KEY"
  ),
});

async function callComputeRoutes() {
  // Run request
  const response = await routingClient.computeRoutes(
    {
      origin: {
        address: "Zetland, Sydney, NSW, Australia",
      },
      destination: {
        address: "Coogee Beach, Sydney, NSW, Australia",
      },
    },
    {
      otherArgs: {
        headers: {
          "X-Goog-FieldMask": "*",
        },
      },
    }
  );
  console.log(response);
}

callComputeRoutes();
```

I couldn't find this in the docs, couldn't figure this out from the library sources or comments, had to just try and got lucky :)